# OpenStreetMap tiles not loaded despite being received

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap

While using OpenLayers to load OpenStreetMap, I observe that part of the map would sometimes be covered with blank pink tiles. I searched and found similar complaints with solutions suggesting the modification of `OpenLayers.IMAGE_RELOAD_ATTEMPTS` parameter to an integer number greater than 0. I did exactly that, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Using Firebug, I am able to verify that the tiles were indeed downloaded successfully. However, for some unknown reason, they just do not load onto the map. I have no issue with Google Maps as a base layer. The problem seems to be restricted to OpenStreetMap only. Any idea how to solve this pink tile of death?

[image: OpenStreetMap with pink tiles]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find that this problem is particular to Firefox 12.0 browser. Google Chrome 21.0 seems unaffected. And only OpenStreetMap is affected, its sister site OpenCycleMap is not. The solution is to set `crossOriginKeyword` in `tileOptions` of OSM layer to null:

```
tileOptions: {crossOriginKeyword: null}
```

Comment: The problem with setting crossOriginKeyword to null is that the offline caching features no longer work. cacheread and cachewrite no longer work. The pink tile problem does not occur in Internet Explorer but exits in Safari and Firefox. I have been try to solve this for the last few weeks now. Any help would be appreciated.