# OpenStreetMap Tiles Not Loading in Firefox 17.0.1 - Pink Background

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, tiles, error, loading

I recently ran into an issue where only a pink background is displayed in the openstreetmap on my webpage (tiles are not displaying). I found this topic [OpenStreetMap tiles not loaded despite being received](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/38943/openstreetmap-tiles-not-loaded-despite-being-received) which would seem to address the issue but the solution presented no longer fixes it.

I tried adding the suggested code to my layer but the issue persists.

```
map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.GeoRSS("My Points", "georss", {
    tileOptions: {
        crossOriginKeyword: null
    } 
}));
```

Any ideas on how to fix this in the newer version of Firefox?

Comment: Do you have a live example of your code? Not had any problems in Firefox 17 with Openlayers

Comment: Just looked at my code and realized it was a *very* silly syntax error. I had unnecessarily put double quotes around tileOptions:. I will close this shortly. Thanks Mapperz for getting back to me so quickly and sorry for the waste of time!